# UI gets blocked while the progress bar gets updated

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I am trying to update a progress bar once an operation is running using async/await calls but the UI freezes while the progress bar is being updated.

Basically this was a very easy requirement when a BackgroundWorker was used, but now using this async/await calls things seems to get a little complicated.

First, can a async/await usage fill a progress bar like a BackgroundWorker did? Is something common between these two approaches?

On my UI I have a progress bar and a button, when the button gets clicked the progress bar starts to update but the UI freezes and this should not be happening since the async/await should work in a "concurrency" way. 
  If I was doing this using a BackgroundWorked the UI was not freezing.

Can someone please explain me what am I doing wrong, and how could I modify the below code in order to keep the UI responsive while the progress bar gets updated?
 Can an async/await usage behave like a BackgroundWorker did, when it was updating a progress bar?

Below is my code:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CallMethodAsync();
}

private async Task CallMethodAsync()
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = 0;
    this.progressBar1.Maximum = 1000000;
    var progressbar1 = new Progress<double>();
    progressbar1.ProgressChanged += Progressbar1_ProgressChanged;

    await ExecuteMethodAsync(progressbar1);
}

private async Task ExecuteMethodAsync(IProgress<double> progress = null)
{
    await Task.Run(new Action(() => { 

        double percentComplete = 0;
        bool done = false;

        while (!done)
        {
            if (progress != null)
            {
                progress.Report(percentComplete);
            }

            percentComplete += 1;

            if (percentComplete == 1000000)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }));
}

private void Progressbar1_ProgressChanged(object sender, double e)
{
    this.progressBar1.Increment(1);
}
```

Comment: Don't await the task that updates the bar and use `this.Invoke(new Action()....` to update the UI.

Comment: Ignore @Crowcoder's comment. Your code is fine. Awaiting and using `Progress<T>` are in fact the modern idiom for this scenario. The problem in your code is that you aren't doing any _actual_ work. You're just spamming the UI thread with updates and it can't keep up. If you, for example, change the iteration count to `100` instead of `1000000`, and add an `await Task.Delay(500);` in your `while` loop, you not only can get rid of the `await Task.Run()` (i.e. the loop can just be in your `ExecuteMethodAsync()` method instead of a lambda), it will work like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is basically fine. The only problem with it is that it doesn't do any actual work, so it spends all of its time trying to update the UI. On my computer, the whole thing completes in a few seconds, but because the UI is so busy handling the updates from the progress, it has little time left for other user interactions. For example, if I drag the window, the window position will update only once or twice during the time the task loop is executing.

In a real-world scenario, you would update the progress less frequently, between major blocks of work. You can simulate this better in the code you've got by getting rid of the `Task.Run()` outside the loop and using `Task.Delay()` inside the loop to represent your long-running work. In a real-world scenario, you might replace `Task.Delay()` with `Task.Run()` to execute the *individual* work components.

Of course, if you do it this way, you no longer need the `Progress<T>` class. It's a useful class, to be sure, but often when using `async`/`await`, the work and progress updating can alternate, allowing you to return back to the UI thread for the progress update using `await` instead of having to go through `Progress<T>`. If you change your code example as I'm suggesting, it will look more like this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CallMethodAsync();
}

private async Task CallMethodAsync()
{
    this.progressBar1.Value = 0;
    this.progressBar1.Maximum = 1000;

    await ExecuteMethodAsync();
}

private async Task ExecuteMethodAsync()
{
    for (int percentComplete = 0; percentComplete < 1000; percentComplete++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10);
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
}
```

The `Progressbar1_ProgressChanged()` method is not even needed, and the rest of the code gets a *lot* simpler. Because I'm using `await`, I can use the `progressBar1` object directly instead of using a cross-thread invocation mechanism like `Progress<T>`

Note that in the above, I'm waiting only 10 ms. This is about the limit of the Windows thread scheduler — it can't schedule threads precisely more frequently than that — but that's still slow enough to let the UI thread keep up with the updates. A real-world scenario is likely to have chunks of work lengthier than that, anywhere from 100 ms on up.

Even with this relatively high frequency of updating, UI interaction like dragging the window occurs smoothly.